# Making a bash script executable without calling the direct path

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to make a function that automatically inserts a softlink into /usr/bin. This will allow the script it's called in to be much more user-friendly.

This is what I have right now:

```
executeAnywhere(){
    local scriptlocation="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
    local scriptname=`basename $0`
    sudo ln -s $scriptlocation/$scriptname /usr/bin/$scriptname
}
```

However, I don't know how this will work permissions-wise: Do I need to modify the permissions of the symlink in some ways?

Comment: Permissions of a symbolic link are not used for anything.

Comment: I can't understand how this could be helpful.  It has to be pathed to at least once, and by someone that has sudo permissions.  Also, instead o dirname, why not just `ln -s ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} /usr/local/bin/${0##*/}`

Comment: and ... why are you using ancient syntax, `back-tics` on the second `local` declaration, when you clearly know about "modern (1988+)" command substitution using `var=$(cmd)` on your first `local` declaration!? ;-) LOL, but Good luck!

Comment: If it's a script for your own use, `$HOME/bin` is the conventional place to put it — add `$HOME/bin` to your `$PATH` if it is not already there.  If the script is for more general use, `/usr/local/bin` is one conventional place to add it.  Putting it in `/usr/bin` is not recommended — that's where system files go.  If you were on Mac OS X 10.11.x (El Capitan), you'd not be able to create the link in `/usr/bin`; it would need to go in `/usr/local/bin` or perhaps in a directory under `/opt`, but probably `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **root user** then you don't have to worry about permissions. But a non-root user won't be able to make this link to `/usr/bin/` directory, since in most systems `/usr/bin` will have either `544` or `755` permission.

But usually in most installations `/usr/bin` **will be not writable for even for admin users** also (`root`). So it's better to [put the link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln) to `/usr/local/bin` if that is OK with you, since it won't be creating an `Operation not permitted` error.

Comment: Using 544 permissions on `/usr/bin` would be eccentric — only user `root` (and maybe user `bin` if `bin` owns `/usr/bin`) would be able to execute the programs in the directory.  `755` or `555` make sense; anyone can access the programs, but only a suitably privileged user can add or remove programs.

Comment: Maybe emphasize that even if you *can* write to `/usr/bin` you *should* not.  The location you should use for any local modification to the system is `/usr/local/bin`.  Upvoted for this, nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Symlinks don't have permissions. The directory in which the symlink lives has permissions (so you probably cannot insert a symlink into `/usr/bin` unless you have root privileges), and the target of the symlink has permissions (so the target needs to be `a+x` if you want everyone to be able to execute it.)

If you only want to give *yourself* the ability to run the script, put it into `~/bin` and verify that `~/bin` is in your PATH (which it is on most unix-like distributions).